# Как в чистом C работают с GPU?

Tags: c, gpu, видеокарта

Я знаю о работе с видеокартой через OpenGL, слышал о ассемблере для gpu. Но как это реализуется без сторонних библеотек, драйвер, системный вызов?

Comment: Никак. Устройствами управляет операционная система через драйвера. Вам нужны ОС, драйвер и железяка.

Comment: Это похоже на дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1567447/

Comment: OpenGL реализуется драйвером видеокарты. Чтобы сделать свою библиотеку-замену, нужно договриться с производителями видеокарт, чтобы реализовали ее в своем драйвере. (Ну или несерьезные варианты - написать свой драйвер или модифицировать опенсорсный; написать свою ОС; спаять свою видеокарту.)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy тогда это сводится к вопросу — как в чистом C пишут драйвер

Comment: @andreymal, драйвер пишется для конкретной ОС. Вам понадобятся заголовки и библиотеки ОС для написания драйвера.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy тогда это сводится к вопросу — как на чистом C пишут ОС и библиотеки для написания драйвера ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @andreymal, на чистом C можно писать программы для исполнения на голом железе. Читаете документацию, как для вашего железа собрать исполнимый модуль, как закгрузить его и как управлять устройствами. Всё будет на чистом C, возможно понадобится небольшой модуль на ассемблере.

Comment: Вообще-то gpu и видеокарта (обычно это тоже пара разных устройств) это разные устройства. GPU исполняет загруженную программу, которая получает поток данных их одной области памяти (используя DMA) и пишет другой поток (это уже картинка в пикселях) в другую область. А из этой области VDU (запрограммированное под нужный формат кадра и их частоту и тоже использующее DMA) передает данные на терминал. Да, при этом еще надо вовремя обрабатывать перрывания по концу кадра (переключать DMA между областями памяти с разными кадрами нужно именно по концу кадра). Это в 2-х словах, а так там много кода...

Comment: @andreymal, по сути работы с видеокартой (VDU). Там есть регистры, отображаемые в адресное пространство. В них вы прописываете формат кадра (с длинами межстрочных и межкадровых промежутков) и программируете встроенное в VDU DMA. По получению прерывания по концу кадра можно переключить DMA на область памяти с новым кадром. В общем, все что нужно -- это описание устройств от производителя (VDU и скажем, HDMI (на самом деле VDU передает выходной поток в HDMI (или другой интерфейс), который тоже надо запрограммировать в соответствии с экраном, на который все выводитсяю И еще звук надо подмешать)